# Object detection using python

Tags: computer-vision, computer-science

I am working on my college project and for that I have to recognize different hand gestures, so can any one tell me that how can I learn this image recognization quickly using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Python, I think you would better use Tensorflow.

Check https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection.

It is easy to follow instructions and they provide convenient script for retraining a detection model.

If you need to train a model with custom data, you have to prepared images dataset annotated with bounding boxes.

Comment: Will it also works for the beginner who have no knowledge about image recognization?

Comment: Yes, you do not have to know about model detail. You can use great models already prepared for all as black box. Just follow their instructions, especially https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb and https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md.

Comment: In my experience, Tensorflow object detection is very slow... If you need realtime detection, you can refer to NVIDIA DIGITS (train) and TensorRT (inference).

Comment: Thank you for your support I will try thi :)

Comment: Hello @user8391970, Wellcome to SO. If this answer your question, please accept/upvote it.

Comment: I don't know how to vote can you instruct me, I'm using app.